# String timestamp to Calendar in Java?

Tags: java, android, date, calendar, timestamp

A simple question which I can't find an answer to.
I have a String which is a timestamp, I want to make it into a calendar object so I then can display it in my Android application.

The code I have so far displays everything makes everything in the 1970:s.

```
String timestamp = parameter.fieldParameterStringValue;
timestampLong = Long.parseLong(timestamp);
Date d = new Date(timestampLong);
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(d);
int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int date = c.get(Calendar.DATE);

dateTextView.setText(year + "-" + month + 1 + "-" + date);
```

**UPDATE:**
Just FYI, the timestamp is from the server is: 1369148661,
Could that be wrong?

Comment: where are you getting the timestamp from?  Some API I know stripes off the 1000's to save space.  i.e. one second accuracy

Comment: From a server which we run. The timestamp is correct, I''ve triple checked the value and it's correct from the server.

Comment: Could you try to do `c.setTimeInMillis(timestampLong);` to see if you have the same result ?

Comment: Have you tried SimpleDate?

Comment: @ZouZou Does not work

Comment: @HanutSingh and Yeah, that does not work either.

Comment: is the timestamp you are getting from the server seconds or milliseconds? Some servers are using seconds for the timestamp so you might have to multiply by 1000

Comment: Your code is good. The String timestamp is wrong.

Comment: I also tried that, but it does not seem to work. The value is in seconds I'm pretty sure.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but I get the same response. I updated the question.

Comment: Okay tested again, and then everything works, excepts the mont, which displays 41.

Comment: Okay realized what I did wrong now.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you get the time in seconds, you have to multiply it by 1000 :

```
String time = "1369148661";
long timestampLong = Long.parseLong(time)*1000;
Date d = new Date(timestampLong);
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(d);
int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int date = c.get(Calendar.DATE);
System.out.println(year +"-"+month+"-"+date);
```

Output :

> 2013-4-21

Care because the constant for the `Calendar.MONTH` is starting from 0. So you should display it like this for the user :

```
System.out.println(year +"-"+(month+1)+"-"+date);
```

Comment: I ended up skipping the Date conversion, but otherwise it's the same code I ended up using. Especially with with the (month +1) which threw me of at the beginning.

Answer (score 28):

You can use setTimeMillis :

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(timestampLong);
```